# install kohana into another website

Tags: kohana-2

I have a website that is built with kohana and another one that is built without any framework. I would like to include the first site into the second as an application ( you can write only a report with it).

The first website it's not mine( I never used kohana) so I don't understand everything very well. Inside a folder(let's call it KOHANA) I have index.php a .htaccess file and other 3 folders:

- application,
- system,
- modules.

I've put the kohana folder inside my website(inside the public_html folder), but nothing works...First I had an error with magic quotes, then with the log directory, the other errors ...and I kept looking for solutions and fixing the errors, but I keep getting other errors. The last one is: logsThe URI you submitted has disallowed characters. It's an old version of Kohana. How can I set-up kohana into my website without getting any new errors. I don't know if I made myself clear. Thank you.

Comment: What version of PHP are you on?

Comment: where can I find the version that it has been used? I looken into some files inside Kohana but I have't found the version...I think that it's old (2008/2009) because of the use of magic quotes that are deprecated. Inside kohana.php there is this line:$Id: Kohana.php 1899 2008-02-02

Comment: Probably in the System->Kohana->Core file

Comment: $Id: Kohana.php 1899 2008-02-02

Comment: Yikes, very old.  Ok, you're really going to have to just fix the errors as you go, or move it to a newer instance.

Comment: Sorry, just one of those rough conversions ;/

Comment: @re_ru Wouldn't you be better of learning to work with Kohana? I can assure you it's worth it thinking long term.

Comment: I know that using a framework is better(MVC model), but I have to make it work untill tomorrow and I thought that maybe there is a better way than fixing errors one by one...I've found the exact version:'KOHANA_VERSION',  '2.1.1');
'KOHANA_CODENAME', 'Schneefeier');

Comment: How can I move it to a newer instance?

Comment: I'll search online. :) Thank you for answering!!!!